# View did not render using require.js text! plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm using `text! plug-in` of require.js to load javascript templates of my backbone project.

Here my  `mini_signin.html`

```
<script type="text/template" id="signinTemplate">
   <div class="cartheadertitle">Sign In
       //html of sign in element
   </div>
</div>
```

view :

```
define(["jquery" , 
        "underscore" , 
        "backbone" , 
        "text!templates/User/mini_signin.html"],
        function($ , _ , Backbone , signinTemplate){
   var SignInView = Backbone.View.extend({
         el : $("#loginpanel"),
         initialize:function(){
            this.render();
            console.log("start");
         },
         render:function(){
            var signIn = _.template(signinTemplate, {})
            this.$el.html(signIn);
            console.log("stop");
         }
   });
   return SignInView;
});
```

Router :

```
 define([
'jquery',
'backbone',
'router',
'views/CartList'
 ] , function($,Backbone,Router , SignInView){
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "showCart": "cartList",
        "*actions": "defaultRoute" // Backbone will try match the route above first
    }
  });
  // Instantiate the router
  var app_router = new AppRouter;
  app_router.on('route:cartList', function (showCart) {
       var signInView = new SignInView();
       signInView.render();
       alert("test");
  });
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

The console result :

```
stop
start
stop
```

`alert` in router is working, but the `signInView` did not render without any error in chrome console.

Any idea about this problem is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: close the string into the alert first, after create some console.log in initialize and in render inside the view to understand where your app stop

Comment: Oh, yeah. It's my bad typo here.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri : Still not yet solve. Have a look at my code please, I added 2 console.log.

Comment: print what you have inside signIn

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri : Output is all the content inside `mini_sigin.html`, but the result executes 2 time.

Comment: Try to remove inside html the script and leave only html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38266/discussion-between-titi-and-alessandro-minoccheri)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the script inside your html file, leave only html code.

Usually It's a better thing to create an html for each template to organize well code and files.

```
<div class="cartheadertitle">Sign In
       //html of sign in element
   </div>
```

Comment: saved my day as well!

Comment: glad to save your day :) @GianAcuna